# Array inside a switch

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I'd like to ask if anyone knows how can I use the same array in a switch with different values for the different cases without getting error.
I have this code:

```
    String [] measures;

        switch(option){
                    case "Distance":
                        measures= {"Quilometers(km)", "Meters(m)"};
                        break;
                    case "Temperature":
                        measures= {"Celsius(ºC)", "Fahrenheit(ºF), "Kelvin(K)"};
                        break;
(...)
```

I'm getting the error "Array initializer is not allowed here" where I have measure={...}

But if I change the code and write inside each case,

```
String [] measures= {...}
```

I get the error "Variable measures is already defined in the scope".
Can you please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't initialize array with just braces `{` and `}` when you are not declaring the variable.  But you can't re-declare `measures` because it has already been declared in the same block.

You need to explicitly use `new String[]` before the braces.  Try

```
measures = new String[] {"Quilometers(km)", "Meters(m)"};
```

and likewise for your other cases.

Answer (score 2):

Just say `measures = new String[] {"` instead of `measures= {"...`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `String[] measures` is not initialised. You should add in values in the array with `String measures={...}` or `measures=new String[size];`and then some values. 
Secondly, and more importantly, Strings can not be used properly in a switch-case construct. It only tests equality and should be used only for `int`and `char`. Cheers!

Comment: String has been supported in switch since JDK 7. See [Strings in switch Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html): "The switch statement compares the String object in its expression with the expressions associated with each case label as if it were using the String.equals method..."